# How to send a sequel string to a database?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

I have a string

`String myqu = " INSERT INTO mytable1 VALUES (1, 'xxx', 5); INSERT INTO mytable1 VALUES (2, 'xxttx', 6); INSERT INTO mytable1 VALUES (3, 'gttxxx', 5); INSERT INTO mytable1 VALUES (4, 'xxgtx', 7); INSERT INTO mytable1 VALUES (5, 'xxgtx', 5); // very long ..."`

I need to send it to the database.

I tried

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(myqu);

// also tried

PreparedStatement prstmt = connection.prepareStatement(myqu);
prstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Both methods work only when I use short strings (like `String myquShort = " INSERT INTO mytable1 VALUES (1, 'xxx', 5);` ).

However, when I use `String myqu` ( 30000 characters), the queries throw an error: `Truncated string ...`

How can I overcome it?

Comment: btw, it's "SQL" not "sequel."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't send multiple SQL statements at once! Send each statement separately! You can use a prepared statement for batch inserts.

Comment: If I split my `String myqu` into many small Strings, it will work and can send then one by one ... but that would take forever

Comment: Google for "jdbc batch insert"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
This will be one statement for the database as well, and more efficient.

or break your statements into many statements.

From performance point of view, first option is better.

I assume your program is automatically generating the statements based on data from some source.  While generating the string, when you reach close to upper limit, stop and send the query to database and start next.